# Where does the Entity Registration module store the signup data and how to delete it?

Tags: 7, database, entities

I am running Drupal 7.50. I'm using the [Entity Registration](http://www.drupal.org/project/registration) module, and I have set up a small classroom enrollment content that I used to test this out.

My questions:

- Where does Entity Registration store the signup data?
- How do I see the information collected?
- How do I delete it?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You need to provide more details, including to which module you are referring.

Comment: I don't know how else to ask it.  Entity Registration (the module in question) stores signup information in a database somewhere.  I can't find it.  I'd like to know where it is so I can look at it and delete what's there.  I'd also love to know how Views work (i.e., how to look at what the View produces/contains), but that's another issue.

Comment: You need to edit the question, starting with adding the link to the project page, the Drupal version you are using, and removing any secondary questions (i.e. the part about the Views module).

Comment: Is that better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where does Entity Registration store the signup data?

Looking at the [module's .install file](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/registration/tree/registration.install#n11), those data should be stored in  the table with name ***registration***. Especially these columns of it should be close to what you're looking for:

```
  'count' => array(
    'description' => 'How many spaces this registration should use towards the total capacity for this event.',
    'type' => 'int',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => 1,
  ),
  'user_uid' => array(
    'description' => 'The uid of the user associated with this registration.',
    'type' => 'int',
    'not null' => FALSE,
    'default' => 0,
  ),
  'author_uid' => array(
    'description' => 'The uid of the user who created this registration.',
    'type' => 'int',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => 0,
  ),
  'state' => array(
    'description' => 'The {registration_state}.name of this registration.',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 32,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => '',
  ),
  'created' => array(
    'description' => 'The Unix timestamp when the registration was created.',
    'type' => 'int',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => 0,
  ),
  'updated' => array(
    'description' => 'The Unix timestamp when the registration was most recently saved.',
    'type' => 'int',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => 0,
```

> How do I see the information collected?

**Option 1**: Just browse this table, using your preferred tool to do so.

**Option 2**: Use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module to create an appropriate view of it, as suggested also in its [community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1463042), i.e.: "***Not happy with the default tabular list of registrations? No problem, registrations and their fields are all Views friendly. You can override the default event registrations list, create additional ones, etc***". You probably want to enable its [registration_views](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/registration/tree/modules/registration_views) submodule for this.

> How do I delete it?

It may be straight forward to just delete the relevant rows in the "registration" table mentioned above. However because of its integration with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, I'd rather use this module, possibly combined with the [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module, to perform such deletes

Comment: Thank you very much, Pierre.Vriens!  I'll dig into this.

Comment: @richrmoore: merci for the accept! Note the minor update I added just now near the end of my answer (about using the Rules Link module) ... Good luck!